# nodejs ssh-exec pipe some data to the remote process

Tags: node.js, ssh

I want to pass output of command using npm ssh-exec to variable (or file , whatever) but not to stdout. This below works for stdout

```
process.stdin
    .pipe(exec('ls -l', config.user_host))
    .pipe(process.stdout);
```

documentation of ssh-exec says below. So how do I exactly pass it to the remote process (buff variable , file ) instead of stdout ?

```
//if you want to pipe some data to the remote process
process.stdin
    .pipe(exec('echo try typing something; cat -', 'ubuntu@my-remote.com'))
    .pipe(process.stdout)
```

Comment: process.stdout is a writable stream. So I think you can use writable stream for files too: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can write output to a file:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var exec = require('ssh-exec')

file = fs.createWriteStream('output.txt');
process.stdin
    .pipe(exec('echo try typing something; cat -', 'ubuntu@my-remote.com'))
    .pipe(file)
```

To get the command output to a buffer:

```
var exec = require('ssh-exec')

stream = process.stdin
    .pipe(exec('echo try typing something; cat -', 'ubuntu@my-remote.com'))

var buffers = [];
stream.on('data', function(buffer) {
  buffers.push(buffer);
});
stream.on('end', function() {
  var buffer = Buffer.concat(buffers);
  console.log(buffer.toString());
});
```

Comment: Great help again. Wonder why nodejs doesn't exit after stream.on('end' until I press RETURN or add process.exit() after last consol.log ?

Comment: Because the end event triggers when it receives EOF signal. Either use ctrl+d on unix or pipe output like `echo ls | node ssh-exec.js`

Comment: that last even is triggered because I got  buffer.toString() on console correctly , but then I have to press ENTER or Ctrl-D to exit to from ssh-exec.js to  Linux prompt

Comment: Ahh I see. The above script terminates fine for me. node won't exit if there is any callback or event pending. Are you running anything else besides the above code?

Comment: Yes I do, reading from mongodb with callback. But when I don't do ssh-exec part it exits on itself